# How to stop Outlook to go offline?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

When Outlook is started and thinks the network connection is limited (which is often erroneous), it decides to go offline. Then, most users are unable to figure out why Outlook does not get new mails, so they phone to the technical support and this take unnecessary time to everybody.

--> How to be sure Outlook won't decide switch to offline in any situation? (except if the user clic on the offile button)

Comment: The most common thing in my experience is intermittent Internent

Comment: So how to make outlook NOT display any sort of warning or behavior when it's code perceives a bad connection?  I doubt very seriously that you are going to have success with that.  When you say `which is often erroneous` .. you do realize that some threshold was met in the code to decide this factor?  I never have this happen on my machine unless my internet is intermittent.

Comment: There isn’t going to be any answer that anyone can write that will address the reasons this is happening to Outlook installed to your machines. Why don’t you just have your users as standard practice restart Outlook? When I have this error, it most certainly isn’t erroneous, it’s an authentication issue which is solve by manually authenticating my account

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked the bottom status bar? Is it shown as disconnected or working offline?

For both of the two condition, first you need to check the network connection as John mentioned. It's suggested that you could search something in your browser to check if the network is available.

Based on the stable network, for status "working offline", it's suggested that you could check if the "Work Offline" is enabled.
[image]

If so, you just need to click on it to disable it.

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.